# CSS animation loop fade in & out 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2

Tags: html, css

I have text transition with keyframes, have 3 headlines which will fade in & out respectively one after another It is working fine BUT I want it to back to ONE again when all three done keyframes

It should work infinitely after completing on ALL child

Animation sequence

**1-2-3-1-2....so on**

CSS :

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 3s ease-out forwards;
  animation: fadeOut 3s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

h2:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: 0s;}
h2:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 3s;}
h2:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 6s;}
```

Here is HTML :

```
<h2>Hello Heading 1</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 3</h2>
```

JSFiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lq4w007u/

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    var x = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
      $("h2:nth-child(i)").css("animation-delay", "x.'s'");

      x = x+3;
    }

$("h2").css({
"animation": "fadeOut",
"animation-duration": "3s",
"animation-timing-function": "ease-out"
})

}, 12000);
```